# `Pool.*_async` functions never ready

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, asynchronous, multiprocessing

```
import threading
import multiprocessing.dummy as mt
import numpy as np


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = 6
    a = np.zeros((n, n))

    def f(i, j):
        a[i, j] = i + j

    with mt.Pool() as pool:
        r = pool.starmap_async(f, ((i, j) for i in range(n) for j in range(n)))

    r.wait()
    print(a)
```

The snippet above will block itself at `r.wait()`. But if changing it to

```
import threading
import multiprocessing.dummy as mt
import numpy as np


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = 6
    a = np.zeros((n, n))

    def f(i, j):
        a[i, j] = i + j

    with mt.Pool() as pool:
        pool.starmap(f, ((i, j) for i in range(n) for j in range(n)))

    print(a)
```

the content of `a` will be printed immediately. So why is the `r` in the first snippet never ready? (Python version: `Python 3.6.2 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)`, under Linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're waiting outside of the `with` block. As soon as you exit the `with` block, the Pool is [terminated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.terminate), which prevents any of your tasks from completing. From the javadocs:

> Pool objects now support the context management protocol – see Context Manager Types. `__enter__()` returns the pool object, and `__exit__()` calls `terminate()`.

...

> **`terminate()`**
>
> Stops the worker processes immediately without completing
>   outstanding work. When the pool object is garbage collected
>   `terminate()` will be called immediately.

Moving the call to `r.wait()` inside the `with` block fixes the issue.